# Unique values in extremely large raster

Tags: raster, r

I am downloading raster layers in R from Global Forest Change (https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.4.html, data produced by Hansen et al., 2013). Each raster has 40000x40000 raster cells (~30m pixels) and weight 20-600 Mb when compressed (so, more than 10Gb when working with).

The data is provided in tiles spanning 10x10º and I need to get the whole world. However, some of the tiles only comprise the ocean, which has value 0 for all pixels.

I am trying to find a way to unveil whether a downloaded tile is only ocean or contains some additional data. If it is just ocean, I can create a custom raster with the desired resolution, extent and value=0 instead of doing some calculation on the raster that takes time due to the files size and resolution.

I have tried with

```
unique(values(raster))
```

inside and `if()` conditional, but that's an operation that takes a huge amount of RAM memory to perform for a single tile. I am trying to paralelize the process to use several cores for several tiles at the same time, and this is the only step where I run out of RAM memory and crashes the process.

Is there a different efficient approach to see if the values in the raster layer are only 0, so I can take a decision on the conditional about how to continue?

This code downloads an "ocean tile" (only ceros) and a "land tile" (additional values to cero):

```
temp_ocean <- tempfile()
download.file(as.character(https://storage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC-2016-v1.4/Hansen_GFC-2016-v1.4_treecover2000_10N_120W.tif), destfile = temp_ocean)
ocean <- raster(file.path(temp_ocean))

temp_land <- tempfile()
download.file(as.character(https://storage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC-2016-v1.4/Hansen_GFC-2016-v1.4_treecover2000_10N_080W.tif), destfile = temp_land)
land <- raster(file.path(temp_land))
```

Maybe it is just the way it is for such files, but I keep thinking that someone might come up with a different approach.

Comment: Using `as.character(https://...)` doesn't work for me - does it really work for you? what's wrong with putting the URL in quotes?

Comment: The `https://` URL doesn't work for me, giving a certificate error, but changing to `http://` seems to fix that.

Comment: `unique` is doing more than you need, since its computing all the unique values (which for a real-valued raster is going to be a lot of values). You really want to test for `all(values(r)==0)` in an efficient way, yes? A test like that should be able to short-circuit itself when it finds the first non-zero value without having to check the rest of the raster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no-land rasters has only 0's, the fastest approach is to know if contains a value larger than 0. Consider:

```r
ocean <- raster(temp_ocean)
land <- raster(temp_land)
```

If you use [`maxValue(ocean)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/1.0.0-1/topics/extremeValues) or [`cellStats(ocean, 'max')`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/cellStats) directly, the result will be 255. First, you need to compute min/max values prior to use one of these functions with [`setMinMax()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/setMinMax).

One approach is to use `maxValue(setMinMax(raster))` inside `if()`. Let's check if this approach is faster (with only two replicas... is a slow process).

For ocean raster:

```r
microbenchmark(a = if(length(unique(values(ocean))) != 1 ){print('land')}else{print('ocean')},
+                b = if(maxValue(setMinMax(ocean))){print('land')}else{print('ocean')}, times = 2, control = list(warmup = 0))
## [1] "ocean"
## [1] "ocean"
## [1] "ocean"
## [1] "ocean"
## Unit: seconds
##  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
##     a 165.04971 165.04971 169.86062 169.86062 174.67154 174.67154     2   b
##     b  57.05443  57.05443  57.17504  57.17504  57.29564  57.29564     2  a
```

For land raster:

```r
microbenchmark(a = if(length(unique(values(land))) != 1 ){print('land')}else{print('ocean')},
+                b = if(maxValue(setMinMax(land))){print('land')}else{print('ocean')}, times = 2, control = list(warmup = 0))
## [1] "land"
## [1] "land"
## [1] "land"
## [1] "land"
## Unit: seconds
##  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##     a 258.7052 258.7052 261.6633 261.6633 264.6214 264.6214     2   b
##     b 114.0764 114.0764 122.4366 122.4366 130.7969 130.7969     2  a
```

This approach seems to be faster, especially in no-land rasters. So, could be an option

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overuse of RAM, instead of `unique(values(r))`, you could do `unique(r)`

The problem is that these are not well-formatted GeoTiff files, as they report min and max values that are not accurate. That is why you would need to use `setMinMax` to use `maxValue` as Aldo suggests.

However, you can directly use `cellStats(r, "max")`. It is not true, that you first need to do `setMinMax` for that.